# Python - Need to loop through directories looking for TXT files

Tags: python

I am a total Python Newb

I need to loop through a directory looking for .txt files, and then read and process them individually.  I would like to set this up so that whatever directory the script is in is treated as the root of this action.  For example if the script is in /bsepath/workDir, then it would loop over all of the files in workDir and its children.

What I have so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

scrptPth = os.path.realpath(__file__)

for file in os.listdir(scrptPth)
    with open(file) as f:
        head,sub,auth = [f.readline().strip() for i in range(3)]
        data=f.read()
        #data.encode('utf-8')

pth = os.getcwd()

print head,sub,auth,data,pth
```

This code is giving me an invalid syntax error and I suspect that is because `os.listdir` does not like file paths in standard string format.  Also I dont think that I am doing the looped action right.  How do I reference a specific file in the looped action?  Is it packaged as a variable?

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 12):

```
import os, fnmatch

def findFiles (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join(root, file)
```

Use it like this, and it will find all text files somewhere within the given path (recursively):

```
for textFile in findFiles(r'C:\Users\poke\Documents', '*.txt'):
    print(textFile)
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` expects a directory as input. So, to get the directory in which the script resides use:

```
scrptPth = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

---

Also, `os.listdir` returns just the filenames, not the full path.
So `open(file)` will not work unless the current working directory happens to be the directory where the script resides. To fix this, use `os.path.join`:

```
import os

scrptPth = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for file in os.listdir(scrptPth):
    with open(os.path.join(scrptPth, file)) as f:
```

---

Finally, if you want to recurse through subdirectories, use `os.walk`:

```
import os

scrptPth = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scrptPth):
    for filename in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            head,sub,auth = [f.readline().strip() for i in range(3)]
            data=f.read()
            #data.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: So I tried that and I am still getting an invalid syntax error on the way I am calling that variable.

Comment: You also need a colon at the end of `for file in os.listdir(scrptPth):` . Without the colon, you would get a SyntaxError.